# Constructor usages in Java

Tags: java, constructor

Can anybody explain the differences between these constructors. See this;

```
  public MyClass() {
  }
```

and

```
  public MyClass() {
      this();
  }
```

and

```
  public MyClass() {
      super();
  }
```

Comment: Second one is not a valid.. It will be recursive call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second is not allowed to be declared in java because you are making recursive call to default constructor only. Also by default constructor has always super() method which is inserted by compiler if not specified explicitly.

Comment: This seems to be only correct answer here - the compiler prevents the second formation.

Answer (score 2):

```
public MyClass() { }
```

declares an empty no-arg constructor. If you declare no constructor for a class, the compiler effectively inserts this conrtsuctor for the class.

```
public MyClass() { this(); }
```

will not compile.

```
public MyClass() { super(); }
```

is a constructor which invokes the default constructor of the super-class. This will compile only if the super-class has a default constructor, or no constructor (in which case, the compiler inserts a default constructor anyways, as mentioned above). Also, leaving out the `super();` call has the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in the second case you probably *meant* to write:

```
public MyClass() {
  super();       // not "this();"
}
```

Either way, your second case is a compilation error.  The JLS says this:

> *"It is a compile-time error for a constructor to directly or indirectly invoke itself through a series of one or more explicit constructor invocations involving this."* [JLS 8.8.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7)

In your example, `this()` is an explicit constructor invocation that directly invokes the same constructor.

---

Finally, there is no semantic difference between the first and third forms.  The first form has an **implicit** invocation of the no-args constructor of the superclass, and the third for just makes that invocation **explicit**.

Some people prefer to write the form with an explicit invocation for the sake of readability, but IMO it doesn't really make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple

Let me make you understand

first

```
public MyClass() {  }
```

is simply a default public constructor

But when you write this

```
public MyClass() { this(); }
```

that means you are applying constructor chaining. Constructor Chaining is simply calling another constructor of the same class. This must be the first statement of the Constructor. But in your scenario you are passing nothing in `this();` that means you are again calling the same constructor which will result in infinite loop. your class may have another constructor like this

```
public MyClass(int a) { }
```

then you may have called this

```
public MyClass(){ this(10); }
```

the above statement will make you to jump to the constructor receiving the same arguments that you have passed

Now,

```
public Myclass(){ super(); }
```

signifies that you are calling the constructor of the super class which is inherited by the class `MyClass`. the same scenario occurs here, you have passed nothing in the `super();` which will call the default constructor of the Super class.

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at the three type of constructor calls one by one.Each one has special purpose associated with them. But the concept is simple and very interesting to explore.

Case 1 :-  This is default constructor with no arguments

```
        public class MyClass{             
         public MyClass(){ 
            } 
         }
```

The compiler will automatically supply a no-argument constructor for you if you do not write one.Thus if you write `public class MyClass{ }` .

This is equivalent to writing

`public class MyClass{

   MyClass(){   }
       }`

Points to be noted :-

1. Compiler automatically provide "super" when you do not use super "as the first line of the constructor". NOTE:- For "super" and "this" when you use in constructors always write them in the first line of your constructor code otherwise compiler will give error.
2. Even when you do not extend MyClass here compiler will give call to constructor to super Object class which is the root class of every class you create.

Case 2:- The use of "this".

Constructors use "this" to refer to another constructor in the same class with a different parameter list.

```
       public MyClass() { 
        this();
          }
```

So the above code will give  compilation error "Recursive Constructor Invocation" as it is calling the same constructor and will end up in an infinite loop. To make this work you can instead write

```
public MyClass(String str){
 System.out.println("constructor with arg "+ str);
 }
public MyClass(){
this("Cons");      // note that "this" has to be at first line otherwise compiler gives error
System.out.println("constructor with no arg");
  }
```

Here you can see the importance of "this" in constructors. It is used to call constructors from another constructor in the same function.

Case 3:- Use of "Super". Super is used to make a call to  no-arg constructor of super call. Rest information is mentioned in Case 1 already.

```
         public MyClass() { 
         super();
         }
```

Comment: You can refer to a nice article here http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-2000/jw-1013-constructors.html

Answer (score 0):

`this()` will be used to call `MyClass()` **No-Args Constructor.**

Though it will give `Recurssion constructor error` during **Compilation**

**Eg:**

```
public MyClass{


   public MyClass(){

  this(5);     // Here this(5) will be used to call the MyClass Constructor with
               // int value as Parameter
    }


   public MyClass(int i){



    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case the constructor will insert a silent call to no argument constructor of the super-class which I guess in this case will be the Object class. In the second case the this() call will call the no argument constructor of class. It can sometimes cause an error too.

Answer (score 0):

The second one will surely <strike>cause an OutOfMemoryError exception due to a stack overflow</strike> not compile due to a `Recursive constructor invocation` error as you're calling the same constructor from itself. Did you mean to write

```
super();
```

? In that case both forms are identical.

```
public MyClass() {
}
```

Will call the default no-args constructor of the base class implicitly, if it exists.

Comment: Firstly, stack overflows throw StackOverflowError, not OutOfMemoryError. And secondly, the second one wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @yshavit indeed. Couldn't remember and didn't have Eclipse open to quickly verify.

Answer (score 0):

The first is the default empty constructor. It simply does nothing. If you don't have other constructors (with arguments), you don't have to define this sort of constructor at all. It is implicitly made default if no constructors are defined.

The second calls itself which causes a recursive loop, hence is forbidden.

The third calls the default no-args constructor of the super class but does nothing more. The super class is the one that your class `extends` from, or `Object` (implicitly extended if you don't specify the `extends` keyword).

Answer (score 0):

From within a constructor, you can also use the this keyword to call another constructor in the same class. Doing so is called an explicit constructor invocation
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

```
public class Rectangle {
    private int x, y;
    private int width, height;

    public Rectangle() {
        this(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
        this(0, 0, width, height);
    }
    public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

}
```

But second one leads to recursive constructor invocation and not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

```
public MyClass() {  }
```

--> this is normal constructor also called default constructor.

```
  public MyClass() {
      this();
  }
```

--> You are making constructor recursive. Don't use this way. Well you can make use of `this()` like :

```
public MyClass() {
    this(1); // always intitalize to 1
}


public MyClass(int i) {
    this.i=i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. default constructor doing nothing special. each class in java has it per default until you write your own constructor, then you have to define it by your own again

   public A() {}

   public A(int value) {}
2. is the default constructor with a recursive call on it (invalid and shouldnt be used). with `this()` you call default constructor. for example with `this(5)` you call a defined constructor which takes an int value as parameter like the example from 1.

   public A() { this(5); }

   public A(int value) {}
3. default constructor which calls the default constructor from your super class

   abstract class A {
        public A() {}
   }

   class B extends A {
        public B() { 
           /* calls A() */
           super();
   }